# Subdivision issues

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

[image]

Hello, this is my first model and I'm nearing completion. Whenever I try to subdivide, this stuff happens. I've tried to figure out the problem, but I can't find it. Is this a common issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Most likely you have bad topoly. That looks like an issue cause by ngons, but it is impossible to know without looking at your mesh topology or wireframe. Fix it by using [good topology](http://topologyguides.com) and avoiding faces with more than four sides

Comment: Ngons, Ngons, Ngons, Ngons and Ngons.  Try not to leave too many Ngons alone if you intend to subdivide.  Even though Ngons can be a good friend at sometimes, most of the times, it's your enemy.  Go make those Ngons into Quads, and you'll see most of your model's problem go away.

Answer (score 1):

Make you're sharp edges then increase the mean crease under your tool panel to 1. This will cause the sub surf to conform you your sharps.

Comment: Crease... Is not very useful when there are this much Ngons.

Comment: Triangulating mesh or remeshing can help. Though if we being honest the best approach is always retopology.